# Given a Rails path as a string, add some parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, path

Given a string containing an arbitrary path:

```
s = "/api/doctors/123/patients?page=4&active=true"
```

What's the best way to add another parameter to this path? I'm looking for something with behavior like the following:

```
merge_parameters s, :foo => 'bar'
# => "/api/doctors/123/patients?page=4&active=true&foo=bar"

merge_parameters s, :page => 5
# => "/api/doctors/123/patients?page=5&active=true"
```

Does this exist?

---

What I'm looking to do is to add a `next` link in my API for pagination, so that clients know how to get the next page of results:

```
{
  "results": [ {...}, {...}, ... ]
  "next": "/api/doctors/123/patients?page=5"
}
```

My hope is that I can use `request.path` and this method to produce the next page of results.

Comment: If using routing helpers and not an string containing an arbitrary path : say, `users_path` produces `"/users"`, then  `users_path(:foo => "bar", :foo1 => "bar1")` produces `"/users?foo1=bar1&foo=bar"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class for this.

```
>rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.6)
1.9.3p194 :001 > a = URI.parse("/api/doctors/123/patients?page=4&active=true")
 => #<URI::Generic:0x007fa27c33f6f0 URL:/api/doctors/123/patients?page=4&active=true> 
1.9.3p194 :002 > a.path
 => "/api/doctors/123/patients" 
1.9.3p194 :003 > a.query
 => "page=4&active=true"
```

Split the params into a hash, merge it with new values, hash to string, reassign and then uri to string or variations of.